# How can I increase the Linux partition size on a dual-boot system?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.10

My laptop is running Windows 7. I created a partition and installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it. So now I have both running OK.

The problem is that now I need more space on the Linux partition. Using the same software that I used to create this partition, I can only delete it now. I have used other partition software tools in windows with the same result. The default Ubuntu software doesnt enable increse/decrease any of the partitions either.

How could this be done? If possible, not deleting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Start by garbing yourself a copy of [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), and follow the instructions to create a bootable iso / usb stick.

I'd then suggest you make a backup of both your Windows and Linux installs, as any resizing exercise can fail.

Assuming you've allocated all the space on your drive you'll first want to shrink your Windows (VFAT/NTFS) partition(s), to free some space for Linux.

Once done, and tested (can still boot both OS's) you can either attempt to expand the existing Linux ext3/ext4 partition into the free space, or alternatively create a new partition, boot to Linux in single user mode, mount the new partition under a temporary mount point (empty directory) and copy the contents of an existing directory e.g. either: /usr/, /srv/, /opt/....  to it, unmount the partition, delete the contents of the original directory, and then re-mount under that directory, tweak the /etc/fstab and re-boot.